# Grails upgrade to 2.2.2 fails with ClassNotFoundException on migration script

Tags: grails, grails-2.2

I'm getting a strange stack trace when trying to upgrade my Grails project from 2.1.1 to 2.2.2,

```
| Error 2013-05-01 17:54:46,935 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: devportal.schema.schema-0
Message: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: devportal.schema.schema-0
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

Caused by GrailsConfigurationException: Class not found loading Grails application: devportal.schema.schema-0
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run      in     ''
^   680 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread

Caused by ClassNotFoundException: devportal.schema.schema-0
->> 202 | run      in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   190 | findClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|   306 | loadClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run . .  in     ''
^   680 | run      in java.lang.Thread
```

For some reason it looks like it is trying to run my database migrations from the [Database Migrations plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration).

I found a [mailing list post](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Database-migration-issue-with-2-2-upgrade-td4639493.html) on the subject,

> It looks like I can actually add:
>        package current
>        to my migrations to fix the problem.
>        Maybe I should have had this all along?

But adding my package to my scripts didn't help (I even tried `current`).

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution almost directly after posting,

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Nested-folder-for-database-migrations-in-Grails-2-2-x-td4642106.html

> To follow up, I solved the problem by adding a package declaration to
>   the beginning of the migration script files that matches the folder
>   structure. Not sure if it's a Grails change or a Groovy change that
>   caused the problem, but the files were being compiled into a the
>   target/classes directory using the declared package structure (which
>   in this case was nothing, resulting in them being at the root folder).
>   However, Grails was detecting the files in the file structure and
>   creating Spring FileSystemResources with paths to match that. These
>   were passed to the DefaultGrailsApplication constructor and the
>   ClassLoader failed to the find the classes at the matching locations.
>
> grails-app/migrations/releases/release_1/foo.groovy ->
>   target/classes/foo.class
>
> By adding 'package releases.release_1' to the beginning of foo.groovy,
>   then the following occurred:
>
> grails-app/migrations/releases/release_1/foo.groovy ->
>   target/classes/releases/release_1/foo.class
>
> Then the ClassLoader found the corresponding class file for the
>   FileSystemResource.